# How to handle fetch errors?

Tags: javascript, fetch-api

I know there is a lot of questions about fetch erros, but it seems that no one is of any help to me. Every site or documentation say that fetch doesn't throw on errors, but that doesn't seem to be correct. What happens is that 404 errors, for example, throws on console but then goes for the  `then` call instead of the catch. So, the question is, how to avoid the noise of the error on image?

[image]

I tested the same fake fetch call on Edge browser and the same happens, the then part is called but an error is logged into the console. How can I avoid it?

Comment: the devtools will show network failures. `fetch` will resolve into calling `then` you have to look at the `Response` and look accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Use `catch`.

`fetch('/fake').then(console.log).catch(() => doSomethingFun());`

Comment: Does nothing. Doen't even get called.